# É apropriado pedir ajuda para desenvolver ou modificar um algoritmo?

Tags: suporte

Estou tentando desenvolver um algoritmo que em alguns casos gera um resultado errado; não por um erro no código, e sim por falha do algoritmo.

Estou em dúvida: é apropriado pedir ajuda para recriar ou modificar o algoritmo?

### Edit

É uma dúvida sobre perguntas do tipo:

> Quero fazer uma função que monta uma matriz, tendo um número inteiro
>   como argumento. Como posso fazê-la?

Que eu acho inapropriada, pois não demonstra muito esforço.

Já considero apropriada se fosse assim:

> Fiz uma função que recebe um argumento inteiro. Ela gera o resultado
>   correto quando o argumento é par, mas não quando ele é ímpar. O que
>   posso fazer?
>
> ```
> def montarMatriz(n):
>     //faz alguma cosia
> ```
>
> Exemplo: quando entro `n = 3` recebo `A`, mas deveria ser `B`. Como
>   posso corrigir minha função para dar o resultado correto?

---

Ao pensar essa pergunta no Meta, acho que resolvi minha própria dúvida sobre como "pedir ajuda de forma apropriada"...

Comment: Eu acho que deve ter pelo menos um cenário de teste onde o seu algoritmo funcione. Na minha opinião deve também incluir o teste na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maioria das perguntas são devido a isso mesmo, o algoritmo (entenda algoritmo como "a lógica do código"), se fizer uma breve pesquisa no site principal notará que muitas dúvidas não somente de erros de compilação ou interpretação, mas sim no uso "da lógica" empregada pelo AP (autor da pergunta).

Se fizer uma consulta assim:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Ainesperado
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aretornando

> Nem todas perguntas retornadas são sobre problemas no algoritmo, mas a busca no título por inesperado geralmente retorna isto.

Ou seja, é um problema no algoritmo, então é um problema no código, então deve seguir as instruções do Help, como:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Veja que o próprio Help fala sobre algoritmos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

- um problema específico de programação
- ***um algoritmo de software*** (<= AQUI)
- ferramentas comuns entre programadores
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software (<= Este aqui também vai bem de encontro a situação)

O que importa é demostrar algum esforço, se apresentou um código mínimo [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e os links que citei acima) então provavelmente será uma pergunta bem definida.